# How to pass `execCommand(“insertorderedlist”)` the type param

Tags: javascript

I want to insert Ordered List in the text area. 
I need the orderedlist to be with type hebrew,
it creates the Ordered List but it does not apply any class nor Id so I can't use `style="list-style-type: hebrew;"`.
Has any one done this before ?.
How to apply or force a class on newly created elements ?.

```
 this.addBasicButton({
            exec: 'insertOrderedList',
            icon: 'e/heb_numbered_list_rtl',
            type: 'hebrew',
            tags: 'ol'
        });
```

expected Hebrew sorted list results number sorted list

Answer (score 0):

```
Y.namespace('M.atto_orderedlisthebrew').Button = Y.Base.create('button', Y.M.editor_atto.EditorPlugin, [], {
    initializer: function() {
        this.addButton({
            icon: 'e/heb_numbered_list_rtl',
            title: 'hebrew',
            buttonName: 'orderedlisthebrew',
            callback: this.orderedlisthebrew,
            // Watch the following tags and add/remove highlighting as appropriate:
            tags: 'ol'
        });
    },
    orderedlisthebrew: function(){
        var sel = rangy.getSelection();
        var range = sel.rangeCount ? sel.getRangeAt(0) : null;
        if (range) {
             var el = document.createElement("li");
             if (range.canSurroundContents(el)) {
                 range.surroundContents(el);
                 var ol = document.createElement("ol");
                 ol.setAttribute("style", "list-style-type:hebrew;");
                 range.surroundContents(ol);
             } else {
                 alert("Unable to surround range because range partially selects a non-text node..");
             }
        }
    }
});
```